# Android: Mantener el menu de opciones (OptionsMenu)

Tags: android, menú

Como puedo seguir mostrandro el menú de opciones de android cuando presiono alguno de los elementos del menú.
En otras palabras no quiero que el menu se oculte cuando presiono alguno de los elementos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Siempre puedes volver a abrir el menú cuando el menú va a cerrarse:

```
@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```

Si esto no funcionase también puedes probar a realizarlo con el método **[`onMenuVisibilityChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener.html)**.

Comment: En ese caso sería recomendable agregar una opción excepcional de cierre de menú (Ejemplo "Cerrar este menú") que esté excluida de volver a abrir el menú de opciones, porque desde el punto de vista del usuario final sería muy molesto quitarle foco al menú al terminar de usarlo y que este se vuelva a abrir, obstaculizando la vista principal de la app. En todo caso siempre es bueno contar con el sitio hermano [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) para tener una segunda opinión al respecto.

Comment: @FranciscoAlvarado Sí, muy buena puntualización. Realmente los menús están creados para que se escondan por defecto. Y la verdad que creo que es lo más útil en un móvil ya que, como bien dices, puede ocupar una parte importante de la pantalla.